# Ruby and Rails and Haml - putting ruby code into the haml page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to figure out how to put Ruby code into a HAML file so I can determine which controller the request came through, and set some appropriate settings.

I added this code to the top of the file:

```
ruby:
  active_is = "#{request[:controller]}/#{action_name}"
```

But it crashed with the error saying:

```
Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.
```

Does that mean that my syntax is off?  How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty leery of what you're trying to do here, however, for a variety of reasons--it seems like there will be a lot of ugly logic in what should be a beautiful template.

Comment: @DaveNewton why suspicious? In a way, you kind of need to put some logic into the HAML in order to know what divs to display and how to display them, no?

Comment: *Some*, sure. Based on the controller? Much less common, and it makes me wonder if something a bit more abstract would be a better option.

Comment: You should use helpers if you're rendering the same view from multiple controllers. But to answer your question add a "-" just to run ruby code and "=" to run the code and display the result

Comment: @Awesomeness Dave is right. You really shouldn't be putting this sort of logic into your views: views should be dumb. Try to write your views more or less as if you were using [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/); you'll get much better modularization and reusability. Depending on what you're doing, the [Cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) gem might also be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Language filters](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#filters) are preceded by the colon, not the reverse:

```
:ruby
  active_is = "#{request[:controller]}/#{action_name}"
```

More often than not, though, it's easier [to just use `-`](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_):

```
- active_is = "#{request[:controller]}/#{action_name}"
```

Comment: Also, since you are already using `action_name` I'd use `controller_name` for consistency, e.g. `- active_is = "#{controller_name/action_name}"`